# MySQL unable to phrase this situation well

Tags: mysql

Say I have a table of ip addresses and user ids.

```
user_id | ip_address
---------------------
1       | 127.0.0.1
13      | 127.0.0.1
27      | 192.168.0.1
47      | 127.0.0.1
59      | 192.168.0.1
70      | 127.0.0.1
```

What is given is a user id, we'll say 1. What I'd like to do is select all user ids that share an ip address with user id 1.

I'm assuming theres some sort of word that clarifies this situation better than "i dont know" but I'm unsure.

I will also add that I am trying to avoid the usage of a subquery.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid a subquery?

Comment: this is something thats going to be run quite often until a better solution can be concocted.

Comment: Ok, yes, but why avoid a subquery?  (Oftentimes people have heard that "subqueries are slow."  That's largely superstition.  In this case, indeed, the obvious and readable solution that several people put forth used an uncorrelated scalar predicate subquery — an "unquantified comparison subquery" — executed just once.  That subquery might be slow or fast like any other...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id FROM tablename 
WHERE ip_address in (
  SELECT ip_address FROM tablename where user_id=1
);
```

Or without a subquery:

```
SELECT righttable.user_id AS user_id
FROM
  tablename AS lefttable
  INNER JOIN tablename AS righttable ON lefttable.ip_address=righttable.ip_address
WHERE lefttable.user_id=1
;
```

Comment: i should have clarified in my question that I would like to avoid a subquery, i will edit it now.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want (assuming 1 record per user):

```
select user_id, ip_address
from user_ips
where 
  ip_address = (
    select ip_address from user_ips where user_id=1
  );
```

**update** This is no better than a subquery, but you can do it like this also:

```
select matches.user_id
from user_ips needle, user_ips matches
where needle.user_id = 1
and needle.ip_address = matches.ip_address
```

Comment: as much as your answer works as well. Eugen was first on the draw. thank you for help anyways

Comment: Yeah, I had finished typing when the "an answer has been posted" popup came up. At least we had slightly different syntaxes for variety. :)